# Attach MSAL Access Token as Bearer Token in Axios Instance

Tags: reactjs, azure, authorization, access-token, azure-ad-msal

In my server, all routes are protected and authorize bearer token using azureAD passport strategy. For that reason, I need to attach the access token that generated in the client to every request to the server. My idea of doing it is attaching the access token to the bearer header when creating the an axios instance. My problem is accessing the access token.

Saving the token in the local storage seems convenient but I've figured it isn't very safe.
What is the proper way of aquiring the access token in axios instance creation while also being able to handle a situation when there is an error (since by msal docs, you shouldn't mess with login/logout status outside of msal context).

I have this function that retrieves the access token silently:

```
export const acquireAccessToken = async () => {
  const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];

  if (!account) {
    throw new Error("User is not signed in");
  }

  const request = {
    account,
    loginHint: account.username,
    scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read"],
  };

  const { accessToken } = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
  return accessToken;
};
```

and this axios instance create functions:

```
const injectTokenInRequest =
  (headers?: RawAxiosRequestHeaders) => async (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    try {
      const token = await acquireAccessToken();

      if (token) {
        config.headers = {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        };

        if (headers) {
          Object.assign(config.headers, headers);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    return config;
  };

export const createAxiosInstance = (
  service: string,
  prefix: string,
  headers?: AxiosRequestHeaders
): AxiosInstance => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: service + prefix,
  });

  instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    await injectTokenInRequest({
      ...headers,
    })(config);

    return config;
  });

  return instance;
};
```

App.tsx:

```
const SignInButton: FC<{ handleLogin: () => void }> = ({ handleLogin }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        handleLogin();
      }}
    >
      Sign In
    </button>
  );
};

const WelcomeUser: FC = () => {
  const { accounts } = useMsal();
  const username = accounts[0].username;

  return <p>Welcome, {username}</p>;
};

const App: FC = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <WelcomeUser />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <SignInButton handleLogin={handleLogin} />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh, I think your problem is in your `acquireAccessToken` function, is that right? You need to know where/how to get the MSAL instance, is that right? If that's not the problem, I'm not clear on what is

Comment: @AdamJenkins I have a few problems: 1. I imported msalInstance from the index.tsx where I intialized it - not sure if that is the right way (but can't think of any other one) 2. I have not fallback for aquireTokenSilent - not sure what is the proper way.

Comment: Do you mean a `catch` if `acquireTokenSilent` fails? If it fails with a 401, the user's logged out and you can just perform a logout action. If it fails with anything else, I personally would rethrow the error and catch it where you're handling the error return from your axios response or handle it in a response interceptor. It's tricky because sometimes these failures can be on "unimportant" requests that don't necessarily need to be surfaced to the user. I'd hesitate to create a "global fail to acquire access token" interceptor/action because it's often contextual to the request being made.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a ton of different ways, all of them can be considered equally "right" (as long as they work).

I'd typically do something like this (my own preference)

Firstly, I wouldn't create an axios instance, I'd do it all on the default instance (which is just "axios"). But this isn't super important to be honest - you can just import your created instance into `UserInterceptorProvider.tsx` if you want to, but you have to create it globally then on startup and not in the render tree (and in it's own file to avoid circular imports). Not my preference, but perfectly acceptable.

```
const UserInterceptorProvider = () => {
   const { accounts, instance } = useMsal()
   const account = accounts[0]

   useEffect(() => {
     if(!account) return;
     const interceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
        // request your token and add it to your headers config
        // note that you can do this conditionally depending on the URL in the config 
        // if you're making a request to YOUR backend, then you can get a token
        // if you're making an axios request to something other than your BE, you can skip this part and just return the config
     });
     return () => axios.interceptors.request.eject(interceptor)
   },[account,instance])

   return null
}
```

and then in my app I'd do this:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
       <>
          <UserInterceptorProvider/>
          ....other jsx
       </>
    )
}
```

Other people's preferences may vary, this is mine. When I'm building a react application, I like to do as many things "in react" (using components) as possible because that's how I think. I personally find doing things "outside of react" (i.e. setting up instances) hard to grok because my mind is always thinking about the render tree and the responsibilities of each component in that tree.